# Views should not be clipped when window is minimized

Tags: macos, swift3, nsview

How to make sure views do not get clipped when window is resized and the size of views become smaller or bigger with the window size? Is there a way to do this other than using an autoresizing mask?
The views in a window i have are getting clipped if the window is made smaller, i want the size of the views to decrease with the decrease in window size. How can this be done using constraints?

Comment: You'll need to provide more info than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should constrain the views to your window edges (their topmost superview in the hierarchy).

First you click and drag holding Ctrl from your view to the content view of the view controller (or window controller):

[image]

Then you make the required constraints so that your views are not clipped (those would be trailing, leading, top and bottom constraints):

[image]